# array or what is this?

Tags: arrays, assembly, masm, masm32

I met a line of code like "LOCAL Path[1000]:BYTE".

As far as I understand, it allocates space on the stack for a local variable, but I cannot understand why there are square brackets here. Is it an array or what?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's an array. From the docs, [LOCAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/local-masm?view=msvc-170):

> The labelId may be a simple variable or an array containing count
> elements, where count is a constant expression.

Comment: More specifically, it's an array with 1000 entries, each is 1 byte in size.